# inline definitelytyped re/definitions while in consupmtion

Tags: javascript, typescript, inline, intellisense, definitelytyped

Is there a way to re/define already in code defined entity through inline definition? Through /// or JSDock syntax or something like that?

I'm developing a custom Bing map html layer in pure JS and I use [Bing Maps TypeScript Definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/Bing-Maps-V8-TypeScript-Definitions). I rely on VSCode Intellisence for that. it has almost everything covered, however in some cases I don't have an access to definitions. For example it is constructed by inheriting the prototype and then by defining some utility methods (that are invoked when the layer is registered by the map):

```js
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/bingmaps" />

HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype = new Microsoft.Maps.CustomOverlay({ beneathLabels: false });

HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    var _m = this.getMap(), //_m will be of type any since this.getMap is untyped
    ...
```

Since the `onAdd` gets redefined by a new function this function's `this` is just an arbitrary one. it does have `.getMap()` in the runtime but I don't think it is possible to define it for the typing.

So can I do something like `/// this.getMap = HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype.getMap` or something like the one below in order to get `_m` typed as an instance of a [Map Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712547.aspx)?

```js
HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype = new Microsoft.Maps.CustomOverlay({ beneathLabels: false });

HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype.onAdd = function () {
    /**
     * @var {(new HtmlPushpinLayer()).getMap()} _m
     */
    var _m = this.getMap(),
    ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just swap it from an anonymous function to a lambda / fat arrow ? `HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype.onAdd = function () {` -> `HtmlPushpinLayer.prototype.onAdd = () => {` that way your this will hold context / scope.

Comment: @Zze What would this accomplish? ``this`` is supplied by invocation (I assume by apply or bind), not by the outer scope. The outer scope's this doesn't have needed methods. Even if this would work I perfer to keep my code es3-compliant, since it's browser js. But thank you.